# Find all Elements from an array which when added gives 28?

Tags: javascript

I want to calculate all possible combinations from the numbers in **array**,  which when added gives the **total**. I also tried nested loops and all kinds of permutation stuffs but nothing seems to work. Any help is appreciated.

```
let array = [2,4,6,8,20,12,14,16,18,40]
let total = 28
for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    /*return all possible groups of number from array when added gives 28,
    where each number in array can be used only once per group.
    Manually calculated answer - (2+6+20) (20+8) (4+6+18) ..etc
   */
}
```

Comment: Why don't you try something and we will try to optimize it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily achieve this result using backtracking. You have two choices for a number either you gonna include it in the `path` or not including.

```js
let array = [2, 4, 6, 8, 20, 12, 14, 16, 18, 40];
let total = 28;

function calculateSumToArr(arr, target) {
  var result = [];
  var path = [];

  function helper(sum, startIndex) {
    if (sum === target) {
      result.push([...path]);
      return;
    }
    for (var i = startIndex; i < arr.length && arr[i] + sum <= target; i++) {
      if (i > startIndex && arr[i] === arr[i - 1]) continue;
      path.push(arr[i]);
      helper(sum + arr[i], i + 1);
      path.pop();
    }
    return;
  };
  arr.sort((a, b) => a - b);
  helper(0, 0);
  return result;
};

const result = calculateSumToArr(array, total);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: I am here after some BACKTRACKING youtube lesson. It was a new concept for me. I couldn't understand the for loop portion. If you could give a brief explanation then it will be very helpful . Why did you path.push() if it was gonna get pop() after a line.

Comment: We have 2 options either we can select the element or not. When select then there must be some way to know where are we right now. So `push` the element into the `path` array and go to recursion so that we can start from the next element. Since we have selected the element before recursion then you need to remove because as you've only 2 options in the starting. So you don't select that element so you `pop`.

Comment: Oh i totally ignored the helper() function after push(), now it makes sense.  Also do i have to change the variable in helper() if i want to filter my result ? `for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    if (result[i].length == 3 && result[i][0] == 4 && result[i][2] == 18){
   //do something  }
}` This will give me the desired result but for big data it will not be efficient. Where should i modify your code so that it only stores the numbers which i want?

Comment: what exactly do you want? BTW It would be better to first understand how backtracking, just take pen and paper and start your code in debugging mode and track what is going on here and then you can understand the whole picture.

Comment: Okay alright. Thanks a lot for the answer.